# JSON response always returns true

Tags: json, codeigniter

I have problem with resolving my response which always resolve as true. I am submitting a form for forgotten password, and i have only one field there, that is e-mail. I check in the database for the record on base on the e-mail, and if the record is returned, i set the json to true, else to false. Here is the code from my Codeigniter controller:

```
 public function checkEmail()
    {     
        // set the validation rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('checkemail', 'E-Mail', 'valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<br /><p class=jsdiserr>', '</p><br />');
        // if validation is passed
        if ($this->form_validation->run() != FALSE) 
        {
            $ids=array();
            $ids[0]=$this->db->where('email', $this->input->post('checkemail'));

            $query = $this->backOfficeUsersModel->get();

            if($query)
            {
                $data = array(
                    'userid'       => $query[0]['userid'],
                    'username'       => $query[0]['username'],
                    'password'       => $query[0]['password'],
                    'firstname'       => $query[0]['firstname'],
                    'lastname'       => $query[0]['lastname'],
                    'email'       => $query[0]['email']


                );           
                $currentUser = array();
                $currentUser = $this->session->set_userdata($data);


                echo json_encode(array("success" => "true"));
        } else {   

                echo json_encode(array("success" => "false"));
        }
        //  form validation has failed 
        } else {     
            $errorMessage = "Wrong email!";
        }
    }   // end of function checkEmail
```

Now, when i check the result in my javascript file, i get always true. Here is the code:

```
       $("#formSendPassword").submit(function(e){     
       e.preventDefault();

        var email = $(this).find("#checkemail").val();   
        var obj = {email: email};
        var url = $(this).attr("action");
        $.post(url, obj, function(r){
            if(r.success == "true") {
              console.log(r.success);
              $('#forgotPasswordForm').hide();
              $('#successMailMessage').fadeIn()
            } else {
              $('#forgotPasswordForm').hide();
              $('#errorMailMessage').fadeIn()
            }  
        }, 'json')
    })
```

Can anyone give me a hand with this?

Regards,Zoran

Comment: If i print result in the php, i get correct result. However, when i try to console.log the output is alwasy evaluated successMailMessage, even when it should display errorMailMessage. Anyone?

Comment: What's the output of `$(this).find("#checkemail").val();`

Comment: and you are missing three semicolons, this statement inside the if and the else `$('#successMailMessage').fadeIn()` . and after the `$.post` ending.. so check that out. and let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly modify the PHP...

```
json_encode(array("success" => "true"));
```

to

```
json_encode(array("success" => true));
```

and also

```
json_encode(array("success" => "false"));
```

to

```
json_encode(array("success" => false));
```

Then modify the JS as follows by changing...

```
if(r.success == "true") {
```

to...

```
if(r.success === true) {
```

See how you go from there!

---

EDIT: In liaison with the OP we concluded that the actual issue was the way JS was posting the data.

```
var obj = {email: email};
```

Should have been...

```
var obj = {checkemail: email};
```

There were also a few specific problems with the PHP that were unrelated to the issue but have now been fixed.

Comment: Hi Kieran. Just tested that, and for some strange reason, it still evaluate true. If i print the output in the php file, i get correct result, depending from the result in the database.

Comment: @Zoran Could you please post the JSON that the PHP file outputs? Thanks

Comment: i always get "true" in console.log if you are here, we can continue on the chat. I work on the code,trying to fix it, but without any luck.

Comment: @Zoran I understand that you get "true" in the console, but can you post the PHP output? What chat are you talking about? Stackoverflow?

Comment: yes. skype is also an option. php output is correct. i get  true or false depending if the e-mail exists.

Comment: i have changed the code, trying to find solution. if i post the output here i will just confuse you more. drop me a line if you have some time for chat or skype.

Comment: Skype request has been sent. Since i have no more right for chat here.(no enough credibility)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() != FALSE)
```

should be

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() !== FALSE)
```

or simply

```
if (!$this->form_validation->run())
```

Is the best way to chekc for false... != may not always do as you expect!

You need to parse the JSON in the JS: `myObj = $.parseJSON(r);`

then use `myObj.success`

Comment: Hi Brian. Problem lies in the javascript file, since i printed the output in the php file and i get correct results there. So if the e-mail exists, i get true, if not i get false. But in javascript i get always true.

Comment: Ok... also :) you need to parse the JSON!

Comment: I'll send better example later... need to get train.

Comment: Have a nice trip Brian. After adding the code about parsing, results remain same, that is i get always true in console.log

Comment: In javascript string compare is not reliable.  Different browser gives different result. So for returning success result use numeric or boolean value instead of  "true" "false" or use some custom function for javascript string compare. See stackoverflow.com/questions/2167602/optimum-way-to-compare-strings-in-javascript

Comment: Hi Shridhar. I just tested the solution that you propose with the numbers, and it is the same, always evaluate to true.